# i want to make my application only in landscape in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, screen-orientation

I want to make my app work only in landscape mode but can't make it work. I have given `screenOrientation = "landscape"` even though the first page will be in landscape mode and other activity will be in portrait.

**XML FILE**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>     

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".IntroHome"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ObjectivesPage"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MenuPage"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

**JAVA CLASS**

```
public class ObjectivesPage extends Activity{

    ImageButton  imgButton;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.objectivespage);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        imgButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonCloseNGo);
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(onClickCloseNGo);
    }

    private OnClickListener onClickCloseNGo = new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ObjectivesPage.this,MenuPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: before postion a question just try it and post your question

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Keep this part of the manifest as it already is. For example, consider the IntroHome activity.

```
<activity android:name=".IntroHome"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape"  
           >
</activity>
```

And for the activity XML, make sure you have the IntroHome activity layout XML **only** in the **layout-land** folder. This way, the activity / activities you have will only show the the landscape version of the XML that you have defined.

Comment: Hmmm... Strange. It works perfect like that in my app. In fact, now that i checked, i had an earlier XML in the default layout folder and the particular shows up just in its landscape version anyway. The activity does not go to its portrait version at all.

Comment: shripal, did you add to your activity?  It has to be in the AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try setting the orientation from your code

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Check this link for more info

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40792/0/page/5

Comment: no friend all the this types of the possibilities i have already tried please any other solutiong.....i am also providing you my xml file in my question

Comment: setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)  should work perfectly. If it doesn't probably there is something wrong in your implementation. I have used this successfully in the past as well

Comment: Thanks!  The XML entry android:screenOrientation="landscape" did not work, but this code-based solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Beware! it will recreate activity which may cause some other problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code as per requirement:

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` and
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

you have to put these code before `setContentView(R.layout.layout_name.xml)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Let me know if it helps!! Just a guess!!

Answer (score -2):

This looks like an old post, but it looks to me like if you set the mode to landscape in the manifest file, and then switch the mode to landscape in the java code, you might be switching the mode twice causing the device to render in portrait mode instead. Try commenting out the code in your java file and see what happens. If it doesn't work all you have to do is change it back. Easy peasy test.