# Can we stop app from going to Portrait Mode, while allowing it to switch between 2 landscape modes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want my Android App to remain in landscape mode only. So, I used this in my manifest.xml file:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

However, it locked the app in the landscape mode and even when I rotate the screen by 180 degrees, it remains in same orientation. Is there some way so that only portrait mode is disabled, while the two landscapes mode are allowed?

Comment: check this out-->

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561527/i-want-to-make-my-application-only-in-landscape-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode

Comment: @aradhna Please remove the comment as both the links are of no use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your manifest, change your activity screenOrientation tag to `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` and you are done.

This will keep the application in the landscape mode in both direction according to the sensor of mobile.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Jagdeep Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256431/jagdeep-singh)'s answer,from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

> "sensorLandscape"
>
> Landscape orientation, but can be either normal or reverse landscape
>   based on the device sensor. *Added in API level 9.*

and the following note would be helpful:

> **Note:** When you declare one of the landscape or portrait values,
> it is considered a hard requirement for the orientation in which the activity runs. As such,
> the value you declare enables filtering by services such as Google Play so your application is
> available only to devices that support the orientation required by your activities. For
> example, if you declare either `"landscape"`, `"reverseLandscape"`, or
> `"sensorLandscape"`, then your application will be available only to devices that support
> landscape orientation. However, you should also explicitly declare that
> your application requires either portrait or landscape orientation with the [`<uses-feature>`](/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)
> element. For example, `<uses-feature
> android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"/>`. This is purely a filtering behavior
> provided by Google Play (and other services that support it) and the platform itself does not
> control whether your app can be installed when a device supports only certain orientations.

Answer (score 0):

on `onCreate` method of each activity :

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```