# Android RuntimeException Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I am making an app in Android but when launch the second activity in my app, it gives Resources$NotFoundException at the `setContentView(int)` method. I have made sure that I have typed the correct resource layout id and the resource id shown in the error is also present in the `R.java` file with the correct resource. I have also tried cleaning the project and also restarting eclipse multiple times. The error still stays. Please help.

**My Activity File**

[image: Activity File]

**Layout File**

[image: Layout File]

**The Error in LogCat**

[image: Logcat Error]

**R.java**

[image: R.java]

Comment: Have you tried to make a clean build?

Comment: Try to remove bin and gen folders from the project folder and then rebuild

Comment: I am not really sure about this, but if You use specific folders, there must be a default layout in default layout folder...I can remember that I had a similar problem in the past

Comment: @ManuToMatic Yes I did.

Comment: @user527759 cleaning the project removes those folders

Comment: @FrankN.Stein As I mentioned in the question, I already tried that.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I was building a simpler version of the app days ago, and I used the exact same code and folders in that and it worked then.

Comment: @CodePro_NotYet unfortunately not always. I had an issue with that.

Comment: @user527759 I might be wrong, but it is possible that you had automatic build enabled, so cleaning was immediately followed by building, hence recreating the folders. I myself have never run into such an issue. But as I said, I might be wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put your activity_single_player_add_bet layout xml in another folder (**layout** instead of **layout-land**).

See more here: [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) and [How to Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

**Update:**

For getting layout in **landscape orientation** you have to change **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Details:

- [An activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561527/i-want-to-make-my-application-only-in-landscape-in-android#answer-4561654) in landscape mode
- [Whole application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode#answer-2150558) in landscape mode

Comment: It runs now but in portrait mode. I want it to run in landscape mode.

Comment: It's reachable. Simple set the layout orientation to HORIZONTAL (`android:orientation="horizontal"`) in **activity_single_player_add_bet.xml**.

Comment: Where do I put this attribute? I can't put it in any element of the layout as they will have their own interpretation of the attribute, like `LinearLayout` will make its own orientation horizontal rather than the activity.